# Calculate RTT with millisecond in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, rounding

```
send_time_ms = time.time()
s.send(smth)
s.send(smth)
data = s.recv(1024)
data = data.decode("utf-8")
recv_time_ms = time.time()
rtt_in_ms = (recv_time_ms - send_time_ms)
print(rtt_in_ms)
```

I want to measure the RTT time in milliseconds and as accurately as possible. The output in this code is a number like "1.34564". Is this code correct, if true is it possible to measure the value more accurately?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`time.perf_counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter):

> ... a clock with the highest available resolution to measure a short duration.

I propose using a decorator. This leaves the logic untouched and can be applied painlessly on other functions as well.

```py
import time
import functools

def measure_time(fn):

    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        tic = time.perf_counter()
        fn_result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        toc = time.perf_counter()
        print(f"{fn.__name__} took {toc - tic} seconds")
        return fn_result

    return wrapper
```

Usage:

```py
@measure_time
def send_something(target, payload):
    target.send(payload)
    data = target.recv(1024)
    data = data.decode("utf-8")
```

You might want to switch out the `print` with your desired `logger`.